# Prevent screen from turning on/off automatically due to interaction with the internal magnetic on Nexus 6

Tags: nexus-6

I have a rooted Nexus 6 running on Lineage OS 15.1 (Android 8.1). The internal magnet that is supposed to turn the screen on and off when a magnetic case flap is shut is making it really difficult to use my magnetic car mount.

Is there any way to turn off this feature?

Comment: I see an old Xposed module https://www.google.com/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/disable-magnetic-sensor-phone-sleep-wake-t3296354/amp/